# Can we define a preordered set from a slice category of locally small categories?

Tags: category-theory, order-theory

I'm trying to define a preordered set $(S, \prec )$ from small category $\mathcal{C}$ using *slice categories* $(A \downarrow \mathcal{C})$.

Yet I want to ask **if anyone can see a flaw in my reasoning, please**. My reasoning is the following.

Given category $\mathcal{C}$ consider [slice category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/over+category) $(A \downarrow \mathcal{C})$ under object $A$. Now take *the collection of all homsets* in this slice category. By virtue of $\mathcal{C}$ being small, this collection is a set. By virtue of $\mathcal{C}$ being locally small, every homset is a set, hence we are able to define each homset's cardinality:

> $|(A \downarrow \mathcal{C})(A,X)|$, for all $X \in |\mathcal{C}|$

I write this cardinality as $|(A,X)|$ for simplicity. So we can now define a **preordered set** $(S,\prec)$ as follows:

> Take set $S$ to have elements the homsets of $(A \downarrow  \mathcal{C})$ and
>   say $X \prec Y $ whenever $|(A,X)| \leq |(A,Y)|$

It is clear that we have reflexivity and transitivity, right? the only property we lose from partial order $\leq$ is antisymmetry because homsets with the same cardinality need-not be equal.

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Seems reasonable to me. Even ignoring all of the category theory stuff, once you've got a set of sets (by any means), you can always put a pre-order on them by doing this.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Andrés

Comment: Note, that a small category is automatically locally small.

Comment: Thanks @Oskar. I've edited my question

Comment: The objects of $A\downarrow\mathcal C$ are pair of an object $X$ and an *arrow* $A\to X$. Therefore, $(A\downarrow\mathcal C)(A,X)$ for $X$ an object in $\mathcal C$ doesn't make sense. You need to say something like $(A\downarrow\mathcal C)(f,g)$ for arrows $f:A\to A$ and $g:A\to X$ of $\mathcal C$. Also, if you intend $A$ to stand for $id_A$, then that's the initial object and all those homsets are singleton sets which is probably not what you want.

Comment: Yes @DerekElkins I see my mistake. Let me think how I can improve my construction. Thank you.

Comment: Even worse, I just noted that at the end I'm getting an ordered class, not an ordered set. My bad. I need to fix this asap